# iTunes Podcast Folders

Tags: itunes, podcasts

Is there a way to create folders for iTunes for your podcasts?

iTunes should have a good way to organize them all, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your Podcasts are stored in `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Podcasts` on Mac OS X or in `%HOMEPATH%\My Music\iTunes` in Windows 7.

There, you can find a different folder for each podcasts.